# Cannot get app icon on App Info in Android setting

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-launcher

I generated app launcher icon using Android Studio's Image asset. Launcher icon is working fine but i see default android icon on App info inside Android setting.[image: No icon on app info]

This is my line of code from AndroidManifest file
`<application android:label="App Name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:replace="android:label, android:allowBackup">`
I am using xamarin for App development. Is there anything i missed?

Comment: Did you try to uninstall  and reinstall the app ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT yes but no luck.

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue,maybe you could share a sample and i will test it.